# Smartest input to <iframe> for youtube, vimeo, ..?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, video

I would like to add an option for users to add a link to a video to insert into the post.

The thing is that for users sometimes this might be confusing, this value could be:

- The actual video embed code
- The link of the embed iframe (src)
- The link of the video in the site

Is there any plugin that checks and turns any of those into the embed code? Of course I could try to implement this, but getting to a stable solution could be slow, and there won't be a point if there is any public feature alike

Any workarouds like this?

I remember of jquery oembed, but this was only working for second option I think

Comment: I typically do this through extending the text editor to have an embed video button. You can then take the pasted in value and parse out the video id, and based on the video id length and characters determine what kind of video it is (vimeo, youtube, etc) so that you can later use the correct embed code with the id.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin B, that was a bit my approach; but with so many vendors.. but it's allways an option ;)

Comment: A comment with a downvote it's allways very much apreciated..

Comment: I did comment. The reason i downvoted was because this question is asking for a plugin, i should have voted to close instead, but now i can't undo the downvote.

Comment: Oh it was you! sorry then! Well yes, maybe closing would had been better approach, thanks anyways ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using oembed in a few forms, but the latest plugin I've used was [jquery-oembed-all](http://starfishmod.github.io/jquery-oembed-all/)
This works for the video url instance.
If you need to allow all options you could use some javascript to detect if an iframe tag exists.